# Cannot save Android APNSetting

Tags: android, apn

I am using APNSetting API as described https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/data/ApnSetting.Builder.
I am able to create the APNSetting as an object in my application, but I need to save this APN setting to the shared APN list of the device (Settings - Mobile networks – Access Point Names) . The building of the object seems is not enough. No idea how to solve this. Am I missing any permission of something else that needs to be implemented? No error or warning is raised. I am using a 28+ API level device. Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: where is your code and what is the error

Comment: Actually the code is the same as example on provided link. The problem seems that the app using API must be a device owner which my app is not... Or is this wrong?